# How do a get a fully qualified domain name of class in Kotlin PSI?

Tags: kotlin, detekt, intellij-platform-psi

I have a Kotlin data class:

```
package a.b.c

data class Example(
    …
)
```

I am analyzing it with [detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) which provides access to the [Kotlin PSI](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi.html).

I'm trying to get the FQDN of my class:

```
println(klass.nameAsName?.identifier)
```

where, `klass` has a type of `KtClass` from Kotlin PSI. But that code prints just a short name of my class, like `Example`, whereas I want to get `a.b.c.Example`.

How do a get a fully qualified domain name of class in Kotlin PSI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KtClass` implemenents the `KtNamedDeclaration` interface which provides the `fqName` method.

`FqName getFqName();`

Which will give you what you want. So:

`klass.fqName.asString()`